# not able to become root becouse of changing /etc/passwd file

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, root, gnome-shell, zsh

I've changed `/etc/passwd` first line:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh
```

now I can not become root so I can not fix what I changed.

Is there any other way to change that file without becoming root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo nano /etc/passwd` to edit the file ?

In last resort, you could always

- boot a Live USB/CD
- Launch gnome-terminal

  - get a root shell by running `sudo -i`
  - find the name of the device of your root partition in the output of `blkid`. If you have used labels, that would help you. otherwise you will have to guess.
  - make a directory where to mount the fs with `mkdir /mnt/myubuntu`
  - mount your root partition with `mount /dev/sdxy /mnt/myubuntu`
- edit the `/etc/passwd` of that partition i.e. `/mnt/myubuntu/etc/passwd`
- `umount /mnt/myubuntu`
- reboot

Comment: Please show us how to mount this root partition!

Comment: edditing passwd file with sudo worked fine. but i still can not become root. i get `Cannot execute /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @Faramarz `bash` is not in `/usr/bin` but in `/bin`. Use `/bin/bash` instead

Answer (score 2):

Press shift on boot screen to load the grub menu:

- Select advanced options for ubuntu
- Then select the first option that ends with (recovery mode)
- A menu will come up when booting up
- From that select drop root shell
- Edit what you want to edit

Comment: When i select [ drop root shell ], I should enter my root password and i get `Cannot execute /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
`.

Comment: see @solsTiCe comment in his answer